# Adding a title to child element of svg:g element in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am working on d3 tree graph. A node of the graph is rectangle 250x50 size. nodes of the graph have multiple child elements.
I have a title for the whole node. but 
I want a separate title when someone mouse over on eye icon. Eye icon exists at the bottom right corner of Node leaf.

Have this tooltip that works when mouse over anywhere in the rectangle(Whole node).

```
nodeEnter.append("svg:title")
                        .text(function (d) {
                            return d.name;
                        });
```

Tried this

```
nodeEnter.append("svg:path")
     .attr("d", "M12 4.5C7 4.5 2.73 7.61 1 12c1.73 4.39 6 7.5 11 7.5s9.27-3.11 
                 11-7.5c-1.73-4.39-6-7.5-11-7.5zM12 17c-2.76 0-5-2.24-5- 
                 5s2.24-5 5-5 5 2.24 5 5-2.24 5-5 5zm0-8c-1.66 0-3 1.34-3 
                 3s1.34 3 3 3 3-1.34 3-3-1.34-3-3-3z")
     .attr("transform", function (d) {
                            var y = d.rectHeight - 32;
                            return "translate(" + 225 + "," + y + ")"
                        })
     .attr("title", "View Details")
     .classed("eye", true);
```

Can anyone please help me to show separate title(tooltip) when mouse over on eye icon, not on the whole node.

Answer (score 0):

in SVG titles has different syntax, use `<title>` tag:

```
selection.append('title').text(d => 'hello world');
```

```js
d3.select('body')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('viewBox', '-50 -50 350 100')
  .attr('height', '88vh')
  .selectAll('circle')
  .data(Array(6).fill(0).map((d,i) => Math.random()))
  .enter()
  .append('circle')
  .attr('cx', (d,i) => i*50)
  .attr('cy', d => (d - 0.5)*25)
  .attr('fill', d => `hsl(${d*360},55%,55%)`)
  .attr('r', 22)
  .append('title')
  .text((d,i) => `circle ${i+1}`);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: selection.append('title').text(d => 'hello world'  gave me clue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The solution I have found --

```
d3.selectAll(".eye")
                        .append("svg:title")
                        .text("View Details");
```